# Factoring code, keeping readability and make life better :)

Tags: d

I'm just starting to learn D programming language, and happily playing with delegate and function keywords. I'm trying to implement (only for my own learning process) the famous Deferred class from twisted (written in Python).

I'm just wondering if there are some tricks to factor out that kind of code :

```
class Deferred(ResultType)
{
    alias ResultType delegate(ResultType) CallbackType;

    private CallbackType[2] _callbacks[];

    private bool _running;
    private uint _paused;

    void addCallback(CallbackType cb)
    {
        this._callbacks ~= [cb, cast(CallbackType) null];
    }

    void addCallback(void function() f)
    {
        this.addCallback(
            (ResultType res) { f(); return res; }
        );
    }

    void addCallback(void function(ResultType) f)
    {
        this.addCallback(
            (ResultType res) { f(res); return res; }
        );
    }

    void addCallback(ResultType function() f)
    {
        this.addCallback(
            (ResultType res) { return f(); }
        );
    }

    void addCallback(ResultType function(ResultType) f)
    {
        this.addCallback(
            (ResultType res) { return f(res); }
        );
    }

}
```

The goal is to permit the user to not pass the `CallbackType` delegate, but some function, with or without the right argument/ return type.
Am I missing some important point here ?

[EDIT]: With advices of [Mehrdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541686/mehrdad), the answer might be something like this :

```
class Deferred(ResultType)
{
    alias ResultType delegate(Deferred, ResultType) CallbackType;

    private CallbackType[2] _callbacks[];

    void addCallback(T)(T cb)
    {
        this._callbacks ~= [this._makeConvenient(cb), cast(CallbackType) null];
    }

    private CallbackType _makeConvenient(T)(T f)
    {
        alias traits.ReturnType!(f) ReturnType;
        alias traits.ParameterTypeTuple!(f) Params;

        return (Deferred d, ResultType res)
        {
            ReturnType wrapper()
            {
                static if (Params.length == 2)
                {
                    static if (is(Params[0] == Deferred!(ResultType)) && is(Params[1] == ResultType))
                        return f(this, res);
                    else
                        static assert(false, "Cannot wrap given callback: Wrong arguments types");
                }
                else static if (Params.length == 1)
                {
                    static if (is(Params[0] == Deferred!(ResultType)))
                        return f(this);
                    else static if (is(Params[0] == ResultType))
                        return f(res);
                    else
                        static assert(false, "Cannot wrap given callback: Wrong argument type");
                }
                else static if (Params.length == 0)
                    return f();
                else
                    static assert(false, "Cannot wrap given callback: Wrong argument number");
            }

            static if (is(ReturnType == void)) { wrapper(); return res; }
            else static if (is(ReturnType == ResultType)) { return wrapper(); }
            else static assert(false, "Cannot wrap given callback: Wrong return type");
        };
    }
}
```

Am I in the right way ? Is there noticeable performance issues ?

Comment: The title of this post would be better if more specific. Not sure, myself, how to improve it exactly, these tools are not my bag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
class Deferred(ResultType)
{
    alias ResultType delegate(ResultType) CallbackType;

    private CallbackType[2] _callbacks[];

    private bool _running;
    private uint _paused;

    void addCallback(CallbackType cb)
    {
        this._callbacks ~= [cb, cast(CallbackType) null];
    }

    void addCallback(TFn)(TFn f) //Put template restrictions here if you want
    {
        this.addCallback((ResultType res)
        {
            static if (is(typeof(f(res)) == void)) { f(res); return res; }
            else static if (is(typeof(f()) == void)) { f(); return res; }
            else static if (is(typeof(f(res) == ResultType))) { return f(res); }
            else { return f(); }
        });
    }
}
```

It's not much better but it's all right I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Is trying `is(typeof(f()) == void)` is the better way to know if `f` takes actually a parameter or not ?

Comment: @Raphael: The "correct" way to do it is to examine the result of [`ParameterTypeTuple!(f)`](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_traits.html#ParameterTypeTuple), but this one was shorter so that's why I used it. If you need more detail, use that one instead.

Comment: I edited my first post using the "better way" :) In fact, I read that the expression `is(typeof(f(res) == ResultType)` checks **type equality**, while `is(typeof(f(res)) : ResultType)` checks **type convertability**, which in that case, might be more flexible :P